# flowchart and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a javascript library for drawing flowchart and  Organization Charts in my Web project,

someone know a good a library?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used it, and it appears to cost money, but mxGraph looks pretty pimp:
http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html

Answer (score 1):

The **`Raphaël`** seems to be very good choice to me so far.

[See Demo Here.](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html)

Comment: you can use the Graphiti lib (based on Raphael). Graphiti add DragDrop, Connectors, import/export, JSON,PNG,XML, to the Raphael lib. http://draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558972/javascript-flowchart-library-for-workflow-visualization) thread might be pretty useful, It talks about graphing workflows (BPMN)

Answer (score 1):

You could try jsPlumb:

http://jsplumb.org/jquery/flowchartConnectorsDemo.html